# ERROR Error: Database not created. Must call create() first

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

Hi my app encounter this error "Database not created. Must call create() first" after added auth service  for Role Based Authentication .

May i know to resolve?

```
core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Database not created. Must call create() first
    at Storage.assertDb (index.js:64)
    at Storage.set (index.js:84)
    at AuthService.login (auth.service.ts:35)
    at LoginPage.login (login.page.ts:54)
    at LoginPage_Template_ion_button_click_19_listener (template.html:45)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15285)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15323)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:560)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:434)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28661)
```

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you use `@ionic/storage` and you miss `this.storage.create();` call.

From [documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage#with-angular):

> Next, inject Storage into a component. Note: this approach is meant
> for usage in a single component (such as AppComponent). In this case,
> create() should only be called once. For use in multiple components,
> we recommend creating a service (see next example).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private storage: Storage) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
      // If using a custom driver:
      // await this.storage.defineDriver(MyCustomDriver)
      await this.storage.create();
    }
}
```

For React, Vue, Vanilla JavaScript logic the similar ([documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage#with-react-vue-vanilla-javascript)):

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

const store = new Storage();
await store.create();
```

Comment: Hi sir ,where should add the above code? in mypage.ts  , app.component.ts  or auth.service.ts?

Comment: @brook18 You should add this before your other `storage` call. It should be the first call. If you use `storage` in multiple files then you should prefer to create a `service` as mentioned in the documentation.